# Print localization strings in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, languages

I want to print all the localization strings in biblatex for a language, so I can review them in an easier way than looking at the code. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is it supposed to be 'pretty printed' into (say) a tabular environment?  Otherwise, given that `.lbx` files are not very 'code' heavy, I'm not sure what you are gaining.

Comment: I believe it would be easier if I could see the result of the code. I have experimented with a dummy bib-file to see the strings in action, but it is tricky.

Comment: Can you not just use the example `.bib` files shipped with `biblatex`  to test the results (just loaded with the right 'new' language in `babel`)?  There are about 80 test 'style' files shipped with the package along with `biblatex-examples.bib`.

Comment: Yes, I have already done that. I have spent a week updating a translation.

Comment: OK.  Then perhaps you can edit your question to include what sort of thing you want to see in terms of 'result of the code'.  Your first question and your first comment seem to be describing (to me) two different things.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Long and short strings for localization keys can be printed with `\biblstring{<key>}` and `\bibsstring{<key>}`, respectively. Many of the strings use punctuation commands, such as `\addcomma` and `\space`. All of these `biblatex` commands are defined only within citations and bibliographies, but we can make them in scope by issuing `\blx@bibinit`.

The default keys are initialized using a list of `\do` commands stored in `\abx@dostrings`. You can redefine `\do` to print the strings in a document. Here's an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{biblatex} 

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\blx@bibinit
\def\do#1{\item \texttt{#1}: \biblstring{#1}, \bibsstring{#1}}
List of default localization keys (name: long string, short string)
\begin{itemize}
\abx@dostrings
\end{itemize}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

Note that this won't print keys initialized elsewhere, but you could append `\abx@dostrings` with additional keys in the preamble. As of `biblatex 2.0` all strings defined in the standard `lbx` files correspond to default localization keys.